# Rendered textures different to 3D View

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

[image]

I UV smart unwrapped the model to a layout and applied the relevant materials and textures. In 3D View, the textures look fine (as shown above). However on rendering, the brick and wood textures become distorted (see below) (notice the roof is fine). What is the cause of this?

[image]

**I have been asked to detail the process by which I apply a material / texture so here it goes.** Firstly, I smart unwrapped the model as shown.

[image]

[image]

I then create a new material (in this case a brick material).

[image]

I then add my brick texture to the material as shown:

[image]

I do some mapping of the X/Y coordinates in order to resize my image texture to fit the face.

[image]

Finally I select the face to which I wish to apply the material and hit assign.

[image]

Occassionally, the bricks will have the wrong rotation and so I will rotate the UV island within the UV layout in order to have the brick texture rotate into the correct position.

In 3D view, the textures look perfect, when rendered, something is going very wrong.

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong texture coordinates. It would help if you added images that show how the material is created and what your UVs look like. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: @cegaton  - Okay, i've updated.

Comment: In the Mapping UV map section, under Coordinates, there is an empty box for Map. Set the correct UV map for the walls there.

Comment: @cegaton - Thanks Cegaton. I've just found the problem. I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some playing around, I've identified my mistake. The XYZ coordinates under 'Mapping' in the texture properties were different for the distorted textures. I corrected these so that the order of the XYZ is the same for all textures. The image now renders correctly.

Example:

Bricks (distorted) was:

[image]

Roof (not distorted) was:

[image]